# How Do I Set a Variable That is in a Separate class from my Main Class when Button is Clicked?

Tags: c#

I am currently making a Donald Trump game. I have a separate class for dealing with all of the background game stuff.

I want to have it so that when the player chooses donald trump as their character and they click the button:

```
private void btnDonaldTrump_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

It assigns a value of "Donald Trump" to my private string variable found in the separate class, where I can then assign different stats to whatever character the player chooses.

Do I just have to make the private string variable a public / global variable or how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Yes, you need to make it public. Or expose a public method (or setter) to modify the private variable.

Comment: how does separate class looked like..? what is the accessibility method/properties -- is it private, public, protected, internal?

Comment: "I am currently making a Donald Trump game." - will it be great?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within your separate class create an auto-implemented property like this:

```
public string someName { get; set;} // replace your private field with this
```

then within here:

```
private void btnDonaldTrump_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      objectName.someName = "Donald Trump";
}
```